# How to know Phone call has ended?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

What is current Phone state at the time of call end.

In android there are three states.

```
TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE
TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works for me. Hope it will help you

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class CallStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private final String LOG_TAG = "CallStateReceiver";

public static String prevState = TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle == null) {
        return;
    }

    String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

    if (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)
            && !prevState.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {

        Log.i(this.LOG_TAG, "Call ended"));
    }

    prevState = state;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE    #When a call end, no matter what, call received by user or not

TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK #when user receive a call

TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING #when phone ring (incoming call)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the call has ended the phone state should be `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE`

Answer (score 0):

Use [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) to to receive notification of changes in specified telephony states.

Overide `onCallStateChanged (int state, String incomingNumber)` and check the `state` parameter

```
if (state == CALL_STATE_IDLE) {  
    //this is current Phone state at the time of call end, handle call end here
}
```

The three states indicate the following:

> `CALL_STATE_IDLE` -> Device call state: No activity.
>    `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK`
>   -> Device call state: Off-hook. At least one call exists that is dialing, active, or on hold, and no calls are ringing or waiting.
>   `CALL_STATE_RINGING` -> Device call state: Ringing. A new call arrived
>   and is ringing or waiting. In the latter case, another call is already
>   active.

For more information, please refer the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#CALL_STATE_IDLE).